# How to capture the event before closing a more event popup in FullCalendar v5?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

[image]

Question:
I am working with FullCalendar v5, and I need to capture an event before a popup is closed. Currently, when a user clicks on "+2 more", a popup is displayed all events. However, I want to perform some additional actions or validations before the popup is closed.

Is there a way to capture an event or hook into the closing action of the popup in FullCalendar v5? I have searched through the FullCalendar documentation but couldn't find a specific method or event that addresses this requirement.

Any guidance or example code on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: No, there is no hook for this currently. You could [request it as a feature](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features), but bear in mind it's more likely to be built into v6 (or even a future version) if it's accepted, rather than v5 which is no longer current.

Comment: Having said that...what actions do you need to accomplish while the user is looking at the popover? It's just a way to view extra events which won't fit. Why do you need to do something when it is being displayed, which you presumably couldn't do if all the events had just fitted onto the calendar automatically. I'm interested in what the use case is for this, and therefore whether there might be a different way to achieve whatever your real goal is in this situation. Thanks.